# Puede una aplicacion hecha en .NET 4.0 correr con .NET 4.5 instalada en mi PC?

Tags: .net

Tengo una aplicacion hecha con Viusal Studio 2010, C# winForms y uno de los requisitos para su instalacion es .Net Framework 4.0 y tengo una PC que tiene instalada la version .Net Framework 4.5.2 pero no la 4.0

Para poder ejecutar la aplicacion tuve que desinstalar la version 4.5.2 de .Net, instalar la versoin 4.0 y volver a instalar la version 4.5.2 de .Net

Es asi como debe funcionar o existe alguna forma de poder correr esta aplicacion teniendo solo instalado en mi PC una version de .Net superior a la version que se utilizo para desarrollar la aplicacion?

Comment: Pues en teoria deberia de funcionar en cualquier versión superior,

Comment: Hay algo extraño en esta pregunta que es "*Para poder ejecutar la aplicacion tuve que desinstalar la version 4.5.2 de .Net, instalar la versoin 4.0 y volver a instalar la version 4.5.2 de .Net*" Ya que eso en mi experiencia nunca me sucedio, siempre que he corrido aplicaciones compiladas por mi mismo en 4.0, en entornos con versiones superiores no dio ningun error. Lo que haría falta es analizar el error.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes mirarlo en [la documentación de Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ff602939(v=vs.110).aspx), pero en resumen dice que con el .NET Framework superior no te debería dar ningún problema, a no ser que el framework que quieras abrir sea mucho más antiguo y tenga métodos obsoletos que Microsoft suprimiera en su día.